# How to add Scala Platform to nebeans 8

Tags: scala, netbeans

I'm trying to use NetBeans 8.01 with Scala, and it can't find the "Scala Platform".
I'm using Windows8.1 x64. I follow [this tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/10_steps_to_happiness_with) and also I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962337/setting-scala-platform-for-netbeans-6-8-on-ubuntu-lucid-lynx) but doesn't work.

I follow path **tools-->Scala Platform** and I have error: **The specified folder not contain a Scala platform**.
I try to add a new Platform but netbeans not find Scala platform.
Finally I try  [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) with scala and it's work.

So wonder if exist bug in netbeans or I must do something else? Can someone straighten me out?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.
I add `"-J-Dscala.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\scala"` to the `NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf`.

Now I can run an scala program.

However if you want to call scala program from java code in netbeans there are two ways

1. you must create maven project
2. package scala code to a jar and add this jar to Java project

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the netbeans.conf file found in Netbeans/etc/
2. Find the section netbeans_default_options.
3. Add

> -J-Dscala.home="C:\Program Files (x86)\scala"

in this section. Do not forget the " " around the path as spaces cannot be read.